# Quarkus Custom Test Profile

Tags: unit-testing, configuration, quarkus, inner-classes, application.properties

I have test profile I am trying to apply to some of my quarkus tests

```
    @Nested
    @TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
    @TestProfile(NoMonitoringProfile.class)
    class ComplexMissionLifeCycleTest {
```

I'm trying to run tests in order, but unfortunately when I apply the test profile it seems quarkus is applying the profile to each @Test in the class and restarting the application instance each time.  This does a few things.  It kills the data I'm storing for my test and more it makes the running of the test brutally slow.

Is there a way to apply a profile to the whole class and only have quarkus start once with that profile?

Comment: A Quarkus test profile does apply for the entire class, thus having all tests run against the same Quarkus instance

Comment: @geoand It is applying it for every Test in the class, but the problem is is that its reapplying and restarting the entire instance on every Test.  I can't get continuity between the ordered tests.  Moreover bc it does restart between every test, its incredibly slow.  As soon as I remove the profile, everything runs fine and fast.

Comment: Do you have a sample application I can look at?